# How to sanitize textarea input for specific tags using php

Tags: php, html, email, textarea, sanitize

**I have reworded this question please disregard original comments**

**UPDATED QUESTION**

If I want to remove one or more characters in a textarea using php, how would I do this?

**MY SOLUTION FOR A SINGLE INSTANCE**

```
str_replace("http://","",$_POST['Website']);
```

How would I remove/replace multiple items or lower upper instances, i.e. HTTP//: http//: HTTPS:// https//: hTTps//: ?

Comment: if you don't know what is harmfull how can we?

Comment: Define "harmful tags". Would it be bad if they added an image to the contents? Email clients already prevent `<script>` etc. even if it's in the email - it's pretty hard to make a dangerous email (other than phishing).

Comment: Hmm I gave two potential examples

Comment: Ok that is useful information. I read of some instances where script tags can be added to a url.

Comment: why is `<?` bad in an email body? no php is going to run

Comment: It does not have to run in the email rather if it is injected into a url that for example may include a script.

Comment: @Dagon see clarification in updated question.

Comment: email clients are not going to run js

Comment: @Dagon - Are you saying the email client will strip script tags from a url?

Comment: @CliffT Even if there's a script tag right there in the email itself - no hacky attempts to sneak it into a URL necessary - it will be **ignored**. Email clients learned in the 1990s not to support JS.

Answer (score -2):

You either should have fixed dictionary for allowed tags and good PCRE knowledge (remember to use lazy quantifiers) or (and this I would advise) use markdown syntax (there are js editors) and compile it in php to valid html.

Comment: Ok foreign to me but I will read up on these things you mentioned

Comment: PCRE is regex vocabulary used in php if that is the point.